# How can C++ array pointers have different location, yet point to the same element?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I know the variable that holds the array stores the address of the array and any indexing on it performs a pointer arithmetic on the same. While I was brushing up my basics this is what I found.

```
int main() {
    int equal;
    char c[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};

    char* p = c;
    char* q = &c[0];

    cout<<*p<<endl;
    cout<<*q<<endl;
    cout<<&p<<endl;
    cout<<&q<<endl;
    if (c==q) {
        equal=1;
    }
    cout<<equal<<endl;
}

//output
a
a
0x7ffda22e0a60
0x7ffda22e0a68
1
```

Derefencing p,q is giving me the same value, yet the addresses of p,q are different. How is this possible?

Comment: This is the same as: how can I write my home address on two pieces of paper yet have the home address stay the same on both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you allocate an array, that variable you assign the array to points to the beginning of that array. The beginning of that array is an address in the memory.

The address of the beginning of an array is the address of its first element, so it doesn't matter whether you take `char *x = arr;` or `char *y = &arr[0]`; they will be the same.

Now `x` and `y` are allocated on the stack and are two different variables, so they will oviously have different addresses. Hence

```
&x == &y // false
```

When writing `T* x` you are declaring a pointer to an object of type `T`. This pointer `x` is essentially an integral value containing a number that represents an address in the memory.

Answer (score 1):

A pictorial representation of your code: (addresses are imaginary)

[image]

`p` and `q` are separate variables, they have their own address. However, the address they point to, are the same.